# Angular - LazyLoading child-route starting with :id catches everything

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have the following routing-modules:

app-routing.modules.ts

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./startpage/startpage.module').then(m => m.StartpageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'shop',
    loadChildren: () => import('./shop/shop.module').then(m => m.ShopModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
...
```

and shop-routing.modules.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'user',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ShopPageComponent
  }
];
```

The problem is, since I'm starting the child route of 'shop' with ':id', it acts as a 'catch-everything' route. If i call 'localhost:4200/user' now, it loads the shopcomponent. Why is that like that? I thought 'shop' was the main route and the ':id' child is only called, when the link has 'shop/' as prefix. If I put 'shop/:id' before, it works fine, but then the route is also callable via 'localhost:4200/shop/shop/something' which is ugly and also my authGuard isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./startpage/startpage.module').then(m => m.StartpageModule),
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  },
  {
    path: 'shop',
    loadChildren: () => import('./shop/shop.module').then(m => m.ShopModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

**pathMatch: 'prefix'** will check for prefix path only and checks for child path for the rest of the path.

Comment: and please do check shopModule and userModule paths once

Comment: the "pathMatch: 'prefix'" is a life saviour but wasn't the problem in this case. After countless hours of searching I found my mistake. I imported the "user" module into my "main"-module. After removing it, everything is working like a charm. Still, thank you very much!! :)

Comment: I also imported the shop module ofc and removed it, forgot to mention.